# Разобраться с метками касающимися потоков (threads)

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, удаление-метки, переименование-метки

У нас есть 2 метки: [поток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba) и [потоки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8). Первую надо вообще удалить, т.к. они бесполезна, а вторую предлагаю сделать синонимом [многопоточность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c). Почему? Потому что если посмотреть на описание метки [потоки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8), то можно увидеть, что имеется ввиду streams, а не threads. Но threads куда чаще встречаются чем streams, а термин в русском языке один. Поэтому предлагаю попросту избавиться от метки [потоки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8) методом поглощения. Для streams можно использовать `потоки-данных`, например.

Туда же [thread](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread) и [threads](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/threads)

Comment: *Потому что если посмотреть на описание метки потоки, то можно увидеть, что имеется ввиду streams, а не threads*. Каюсь, проглядел. Один пользователь массово копипастил описания меток из Википедии. Так в описание стримы и пролезли.

Comment: может быть, имеет смысл заодно разобраться и с меткой [tag:threads]?

Answer (score 2):

1. Текущую метку [потоки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8) сделать синонимом к
   [многопоточность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c), поскольку в ней большинство вопросов все
   равно относятся к многопоточности.
2. Создать метку [потоки-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85) и перетащить в нее вопросы, относящиеся к потокам данных (streams).
3. Добавить в качестве синонима к [потоки-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85) метку [stream](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stream) и, возможно, [streaming](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/streaming).

Comment: *streaming* это скорее из области методов записи данных на ленту, да и *потоки-данных* больше ассоциируются с архитектурой процесоров, нежели с `FILE *` в Си или `cin/cout` в С++.